# node-lambda - TypeError: handler is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

New to AWS and found it quite straightforward so far but really getting stuck packaging a lambda function.

I'm using node-lambda to try and run the function but keep getting the following error on node-lambda run:

```js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-lambda/lib/main.js:93
      handler(event, context, callback);
      ^

TypeError: handler is not a function
    at Lambda._runHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-lambda/lib/main.js:93:7)
    at Lambda.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-lambda/lib/main.js:49:8)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-lambda/bin/node-lambda:89:12)
    at Command.listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-lambda/node_modules/commander/index.js:301:8)
```

My index.js file has the handler declared like so

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context) {
```

And the AWS_HANDLER in my .env is set to index.handler. I eel like I'm missing an obvious step.

Comment: You've named it `myHandler`. You either need to name it `handler` or change the name that you are telling Lambda to look for.

Comment: I knew it would be simple. A million thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {`
instead of
`exports.myHandler = function(event, context) {`

Comment: FYI the AWS Lambda JS runtime didn't support async/await until April 2018, 2 years after this question was originally asked.